# Galaxy s2 phone question

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

Is there any way to see when a text message has been read by the recipient on a galaxy s2 phone and where would I turn that on??? It shows that it has been sent but I need to see when it was read.

Comment: not possible with the standard messenger in android. [How to tell if someone has seen your text on Android](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/mobile-phone/how-tell-if-someone-has-seen-your-text-3605143/)

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking is not possible. The closest thing to it would be a "delivery report", which at least tells you the message was *delivered* to your addressee (it can't tell you whether it was read):

Go to SMS settings and in menu related to SMS activate the request delivery report.

Comment: This will only tell him that the other persons device has received the text but not when or if it was read.

Comment: what I is asking is not possible but the best way is to activate this, to at list know that was delivered

Comment: @JMR that comment should be part of your answer :) You can always [edit] your posts to improve, which I've done for you this time – so it's clear to the reader what you suggest (note: the downvote isn't mine).